# Submit Only 1 of Multiple Lightning-Record-Edit-Form Elements

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

This should be a pretty simple answer, but I can't seem to find anything out there.
I have two **lightning-record-edit-form** elements inside of the same **template** element.  Using the **QuerySelector** or by another means, I want to select only one of them and submit it.  The one I want to submit also happens to be the second on the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to below:-

```
handleClick() {
    this.template
      .querySelectorAll("lightning-record-edit-form")
      .forEach(element => {
        if(element.id==='second form id'){
           element.submit();
        }
      });
}
```

Here, I am accessing both the form elements using **querySelectorAll** and running for each loop on both of them. Then checking the id to identify the second form element and then submit the form using submit method.