# How to submit 1 lightning-record-edit-form and run onsubmit method param?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

when I use the below code to submit each form, onsubmit={handleSubmit} doesnt run. Why?

```
<lightning-record-edit-form key={item.id} object-api-name="professionalExperience__c" onsubmit={handleSubmit}>

this.template
        .querySelectorAll("lightning-record-edit-form")
        .forEach(element => {
            alert('ELEMENTO: ' + JSON.stringify(element));
            element.submit();
            alert('post submit SUBMIT');
            
        });

  handleSubmit(event){
        alert('hello');
        event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        alert(JSON.stringify(fields));
        console.log(fields);
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
     }
```

Comment: Can you separate out your `template` and `js`? Also what is this `this.template
        .querySelectorAll("lightning-record-edit-form")` and why not call ` this.submit();` instead of ` element.submit();` and pass all the fields as arguments.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/277825/submit-only-1-of-multiple-lightning-record-edit-form-elements/327383#327383   here are more info related

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple `lightning-record-edit-form`s in your component. In the method `handleSubmit`, take look at the line `this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);`. This line would query and fetch any one of the multiple record edit forms and doesn't guarantee the one on which submit event was triggered.

Comment: Hi @arut, exactly I have multiple record form.

My problem is that handleSubmit its not been called =(.

All forms are submitted but I cant manage the handleSubmit before submits.


Theres not any way to get all the values of all forms before submit?

Comment: What is `key={item.id}` in your code? Was it a typo error for `record-id={item.id}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a custom submit event handler using `onsubmit={handleSubmit}` within a `lightning-record-edit-form`, then you ***need*** to define a button element (of `type='submit'`) ***within the record edit form***. LWC would then wire this submit button to the custom event handler code. So, on click of the button, a ***submit event is triggered*** and the custom event handler code is executed. Within this event handler code, `event.detail.fields` param holds all the field values that can be updated during runtime.

On the contrary, when you have multiple `lightning-record-edit-form`s, a single submit/save button with `onclick` event handler, and the following code in the event handler, the custom event handler defined as `onsubmit={handleSubmit}` will have no impact because there is no specific button wired up with this handler code.

```
this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-record-edit-form").forEach(element => {element.submit();});
```

Executing the above code does not invoke the custom event handler method because you are not triggering the submit event of the `lightning-record-edit-form`, but directly calling the public method `submit` of the record edit form.

I don't see a fields attribute in your code on the `lightning-record-edit-form`, so assuming that you are using `lightning-input-fields` in your component. Possible solution to your problem is to access the input fields directly in your code. For example, if you had the lightning input field defined as `<lightning-input-field field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>`, then you can access this specific field as shown in the sample code below.

```
const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
    
if (inputFields) {
   inputFields.forEach(field => {
        if(field.name === "Name") {
            // Do something here with the field
        }
    });
}
```

If you have same field in other lightning record edit forms, then you may use ***data-**** attributes. For example, if you had the lightning input field defined as `<lightning-input-field data-id="Name1" field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>`, then you can access this specific field as shown in the sample code below.

```
const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
    
if (inputFields) {
   inputFields.forEach(field => {
        if(field.dataset.id === "Name1") {
            // Do something here with the field
        }
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you may also use `onchange` event handler of the `lightning-input-field` and manage the values on the input fields.

*You may also use the data-attributes at record edit form level, if you want identify and control the submission of the record data. Disclaimer: I've not tried to replicate you problem and test this solution at my end, but it should work.*